# Android Bazel, "Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate"

Tags: android, bazel, androidx, android-annotations

I am new in Android developtment usign Bazel.

I have put the @Keep annotation to prevent the obfuscation. To use it we need to import the library

> import androidx.annotation.Keep;

In the project we've the following BUILD file located in

> platform/android/car/src/main

After main folder we have these packages

- java/com/company/car/engine
- java/com/company/car/wheels
- java/com/company/car/gearbox

The BUILD content is

```
    android_library(
     name = 'car',
     srcs = glob(["java/**/*.java"]),
     manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
     resource_files = glob(['res/**']),
     custom_package = android_package,
     deps = [
        ':jni_bindings',
        '@maven//:androidx_annotation_annotation',
     ],
     visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
     tags = ['maven_coordinates=%s:car-lite:{pom_version}' % android_package ],
    )
```

By default I've `visibility = ["//car:__subpackages__"]`, changed to `visibility = ["//visibility:public"]`, the problem persist.

```
ERROR: /workspace/platform/android/car/src/main/BUILD:24:16: in android_library rule //car/src/main:car: target '@maven//:androidx_annotation_annotation' is not visible from target '//car/src/main:car'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate
ERROR: /workspace/platform/android/car/src/main/BUILD:24:16: Analysis of target '//car/src/main:car' failed
```

Any idea about solve it?

Thanks

---

SOLUTION

In platform/android/WORKSPACE file I've

```
maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0",
        "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0",
        "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0"
    ],
    ...
```

Changing annotation from 1.6.0 to 1.5.0 the same has core-ktx solve my problem

Comment: I think this is just to do with the bazel maven rules (not android/androidx/android-annotations), because the maven rules generate the targets you're depending on and their visibility (`@maven//:androidx_annotation_annotation`) Maybe https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external#hiding-transitive-dependencies has some hints? It might be helpful to add the relevant parts of your `WORKSPACE` file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set `visibility = ["//car:__subpackages__"]`, target will only be visible within the car package and its direct and indirect subpackages.
However, changing `"//visibility:public"`, grants access to all packages and its [correct implementation](https://bazel.build/concepts/visibility#visibility-specifications).

If you can add the sample repo/error logs of the issue it would be easy to answer. Without error log its hard to comment.
But am guessing you are missing some [Java Rules](https://bazel.build/reference/be/java) but can be sure once you share error log.
You can also refer [Android Rules](https://bazel.build/reference/be/android) and its implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Log added, I've forgotten the most important thing

Comment: Can you try adding car target to visibility list. Something like this-
`visibility = ["//visibility:public", "//car/src/main:car"],`